# Get class name that has space between words using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The existing questions I found deal with when you try to **find** classes with names that have spaces, my question is when I want to **get** those names.

To get the name given to the `class` present in each `th`:

```html
<tr class="sub-head">
        
        <th class="photo sortcol"></th>
        <th class="text name sortdefaultasc sortcol">Name</th>
        <th class="flag sortcol">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="number age sortcol">Age</th>      
        <th class="text position sortasc sortcol"><span title="Position">P</span></th>
        <th class="number statistic game-minutes sortcol"><img src="/media/v2.0.9/img/events/minute_played.png" width="13" height="13" alt="Minutes played" title="Minutes played"></th>
        <th class="number statistic appearances sortcol"><img src="/media/v2.0.9/img/events/appearance.png" width="13" height="13" alt="Appearances" title="Appearances"></th>
        <th class="number statistic lineups sortcol"><img src="/media/v2.0.9/img/events/L.png" width="13" height="13" alt="Lineups" title="Lineups"></th>
        <th class="number statistic subs-in sortcol"><img src="/media/v2.0.9/img/events/SI.png" width="13" height="13" alt="Substitute in" title="Substitute in"></th>
        <th class="number statistic subs-out sortcol"><img src="/media/v2.0.9/img/events/SO.png" width="13" height="13" alt="Substitute out" title="Substitute out"></th>
        <th class="number statistic subs-on-bench sortcol"><img src="/media/v2.0.9/img/events/bench.png" width="13" height="13" alt="Substitutes on bench" title="Substitutes on bench"></th>
        <th class="number statistic goals sortcol"><img src="/media/v2.0.9/img/events/G.png" width="13" height="13" alt="Goal" title="Goal"></th>
        
        <th class="number statistic yellow-cards sortcol"><img src="/media/v2.0.9/img/events/YC.png" width="13" height="13" alt="Yellow card" title="Yellow card"></th>
        <th class="number statistic 2nd-yellow-cards sortcol"><img src="/media/v2.0.9/img/events/Y2C.png" width="13" height="13" alt="Yellow 2nd/RC" title="Yellow 2nd/RC"></th>
        <th class="number statistic red-cards sortcol"><img src="/media/v2.0.9/img/events/RC.png" width="13" height="13" alt="Red card" title="Red card"></th>
      </tr>
```

I do it this way having to use `' '.join(th.get('class'))` to keep the real name, otherwise each space is generated a separate string:

```python
thead = table.find('tr',class_='sub-head').find_all('th')
thead_in = [' '.join(th.get('class')) for th in thead]
print(thead_in)
```

Output:

```
[
    'photo',
    'text name sortdefaultasc',
    'flag',
    'number age',
    'text position sortasc',
    'number statistic game-minutes',
    'number statistic appearances',
    'number statistic lineups',
    ...
]
```

Using only `th.get('class')`:

```
[
    ['photo'],
    ['text', 'name', 'sortdefaultasc'],
    ['flag'],
    ['number', 'age'],
    ['text', 'position', 'sortasc'],
    ['number', 'statistic', 'game-minutes'],
    ['number', 'statistic', 'appearances'],
    ['number', 'statistic', 'lineups'],
    ...
]
```

It's totally wrong use spaces in class names, but I don't have the power to change that, so is there a more correct method of collecting these names or the only way is force a `join`?

Comment: Umm... not sure what you're after here? The space is a delimiter required by the spec... What output do you want from the input... little confused here...

Comment: @JonClements What I want is what is in Output (which is exactly what I collect today, but I'm afraid to use this method using ```join``` because I've never seen classes with spaces in the name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a reason for this. This is not a single class name with spaces in the name, as class names are NOT allowed to contain whitespaces. **These are multiple classes** for the same object separated by a space.

From [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_class.asp#:%7E:text=Naming%20rules%3A,and%20underscores%20(%22_%22)):

> Naming rules: Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z. Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), and underscores ("_")

You probably want to acknowledge the fact that these are multiple different classes and handle that correctly.

Comment: Hmmm I understand the use now, it makes sense (thanks for support), but I still need to collect this values in one string as it is when inspecting the html, so the option to use has to be with ```join``` or is there a more reliable way to work?

Comment: I think using join is the right way, but I would use a delimiter so that you can tokenize (aka split) it back if you need to.